# C# Delete String before string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this

```
/CP5/ConPointR/ConPoint/YHO/G1
```

(The string `CP5` can be not only 5 it can be over 9000 (For example `CP71`) and stuff after `/CP5/` can also be any (`/CP5/COND/Pivot/`))

i want to just have

```
/ConPointR/ConPoint/YHO/G1
```

Comment: "over 9000" - heh heh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only string operations you can do:

```
string str = "/CP5/ConPointR/ConPoint/YHO/G1";
string newStr = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('/', 1));
```

Better to check for length before hand to avoid exception.

You will get back: `newStr = "/ConPointR/ConPoint/YHO/G1"`

Comment: This also assumes `/` is always the separator character.

Comment: So does words like "I have a string like this: `/CP5/ConPointR/ConPoint/YHO/G1` ".

Comment: @ZongZhengLi, yeah, that is in the question.

Comment: @paqogomez The default windows separator is `\\`. It will be very easy to make mistakes.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi, how do you know its a file path ?

Comment: I don't believe that is an unreasonable assumption. :) Also, if someone were to look at this, make quick assumptions, and copy+paste this into their code, there will be problems.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi, yeah, but the question itself isn't clear enough, so I will keep my answer to whats there.

Comment: THX Habib it was useful!

Comment: @user2958138, you are welcome, I see you joined today, Welcome to Stackoverflow, Next time if you have a question then you may add what you have tried and if you are stuck somewhere, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: And by the way it is not File Path its Hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. While I'm sure you will have no problems with the code, I'm mainly trying to watch out for others who will happen upon this assuming that it will work for file paths.

Answer (score 2):

```
var newStr = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('/', 1))
```

Comment: This assumes `/` is always the separator character.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi, the op did not specify otherwise. But just replace the `/` with whatever is desirable.

Comment: As I've already debated in the other answer's comments, it could be variable. However, it seems everyone's satisfied with strictly answering the question so I will just hope no one will decide to use this directly on Windows filepaths.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"/(.*?)(/.+)", "$2", RegexOptions.None);
```